# Add colon: after specified number of letters/numbers

Tags: html, mysql, asp-classic

So i have a "Search Box" in my page, 
The value in the DB is 00:12:34:56

If you search 00123456 I can't find the right value.

How can i make it so it adds the colon: after exactly 2 characters.

Comment: What are you searching, a database? If so what database are you using (Access, SQL Server, MySQL etc)? If you provide more detailed information it will help those trying to provide a solution. As it stands the question is very poor, I'd encourage you to look at [ask] in the help centre before asking for help.

Comment: It's MySQL, Also i have a form where you can insert into the DB, i want it to do the same when i insert, lets say i put the value 00123456 in input, i want it to split it and add colon: after 2 letters/numbers then insert it into the database.

Comment: Could you post some code to show what you tried so far? There are a couple of ways of tackling this you could manipulate the input or you could use pattern matching via `LIKE` or `REGEXP` in MySQL to match it etc. What have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not tested, but...

```
    a = "00123456"
    b = ""
    for i = 1 to len(a) step 2
       b = b & ":" & mid(a, i, 2)
    next
    ' remove the first :
    b = right(b, len(b) - 1)
    response.write(a & " --> " & b)
```

Comment: Would have been nice to wait to see what the OP posted to see what they have tried first.

Comment: From those offered, it is the only correct answer to "Add colon: after specified number of letters/numbers". ;)

Answer (score -1):

**Other solution :-**

When you get your value from DB replace ":" with blank value and then compare input value with formatted DB value.

**E.g.**

your DB value

```
var Dbval = 00:12:34:56
```

Format that value

```
Dbval = Dbval.Replace(":","");
```

now Dbval will be "00123456"

Now you can compare this value with input value.

Hope this help.

Comment: Better solution but why not just do this at the MySQL server? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE(field, ':', '') = REPLACE(?, ':', '')` *(`?` is assuming your using parametrised queries in Classic ASP using `ADODB.Command` object)*.

Comment: @Lankymart - I believe it is always good to do manipulation with data at your business logic , so that select * query will provide actual data and we can use same at other places.

Comment: You can still do that, just depends on how you approach it. Not sure returning all the records then comparing the value is the way to go.

Comment: Yes @Lankymart - your approach is good. My approach we can use when user do not have permissions on alter query and API is providing list of data then we can format data in code.

Comment: Not sure if the examples won't confuse the OP further what is that [tag:jscript]? Might be worth mentioning that also `Dbval` should be a string.